# Array of structures lose data while passing it in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, structure

I don't understand why `printq()` function prints 0, but when I access it back in `main()` it prints. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I tried using pointers, but I get some different error in the priority queue. I want to print elements in array `pq[10]`.

EDIT: I realized that the elements are stored but when I use `pq[R].data` it prints
but when I use `pq[i].data` in `printq()` and put it inside for loop, it prints zero.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int F = -1, R = -1;
int item, max = 10;

struct prioq {
    int data;
    int prio;
};

struct prioq pq[10] = { 0 };

void printq()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d,", pq[i].data);
    printf("QUEUE :");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%d,", pq[i].data);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("PRIO  :");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%d,", pq[i].prio);
    }
}

void enqueue(int item, int p, struct prioq pq[])
{
    if (F == -1 && R == -1 || F > R) {
        F == 0;
        R == 0;
        pq[R].data = item;
        pq[R].prio = p;

        printf("%d", pq[R].data);
        printf("%d", pq[R].prio);
        printq();

    } else if (R == max-1 || R > max) {
        printf("overflow\n");
    } else if (R < max) {
        R++;
        pq[R].data = item;
        pq[R].prio = p;
        printq();
    }
}

void dequeue(struct prioq pq[])
{
    int large = 0;
    if (F == -1) {
        printf("underflow\n");
    } else {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (pq[i].prio > large) {
                large = i;
            }
        }
    }

    item = pq[large].data;
    pq[large].prio = 0;
    pq[large].data = 0;

    printf("item deleted: %d\n", item);

    printq();
}

void main()
{
    int item = 0;
    int c = 0, p = 0;

    do {
        printf("choose your option\n");
        printf("1.Insert, 2.Delete, 3.Exit\n" );
        scanf("%d", &c);
        switch (c) {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the priority and element to insert\n");
                scanf("%d %d", &item, &p);
                enqueue(item,p,pq);
                printf("%d", pq[R].data);
                printf("%d", pq[R].prio);
                break;

            case 2:
                dequeue(pq);
                break;

            default:
                c = 3;
                break;
        }
    } while (c != 3);
    printf("exited\n");
}
```

Comment: C++ is not C, it is a completely different language. Please don't use the C++ tag for C code.

Comment: srry i am new to stackoverflow i just used the recommended tag

Comment: Have you tried running your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine at which point your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you probably want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Even if using a debugger does not actually solve the problem, it should at least help you to isolate the problem further and to create a [mre], so that it will be easier for other people to help you. Most people will not be willing to debug your whole program for you, as that should be your job.

Comment: I just looked around more and found the "=" error which should be "==", thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

In your `enqueue` function, change the `==` in the `F` and `R` assignments to `=`.

```
void enqueue(int item, int p, struct prioq pq[])
{
    if (F == -1 && R == -1 || F > R) {
        F = 0; // Here
        R = 0; // And here
        pq[R].data = item;
        pq[R].prio = p;

        printf("%d", pq[R].data);
        printf("%d", pq[R].prio);
        printq();

    } else if (R == max-1 || R > max) {
        printf("overflow\n");
    } else if (R < max) {
        R++;
        pq[R].data = item;
        pq[R].prio = p;
        printq();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got it :)